# reading FPGA's block RAM from pc

Tags: fpga, xilinx, xilinx-ise

I am using Xilinx ISE 14.7 synthesizer. I am able to initialize my BRAM with a .coe file and access it. Also I can update it with new .mem file using data2mem tool and update my bit file. Here I have configured it as ROM.

My problem is, I don't know how to store the BRAM contents to a file. I am using Single port block memory from the core generator. I am configuring it as RAM. I want to write data to it and access it later. I didn't find any relevant post stating this. May be its only me who didnt find a way to save the contents to a file. For example, in Altera in-system memory content editor, there is an option to export the data to a file. Is there any such way in Xilinx or some way to do it with data2mem tool?

I can send the memory content to PC using serial port but that's not my concern right now. I am really looking for some way to store the content to a file (probably a .mem file) and use it in MATLAB. Can anyone explain it to me or point a document or some link. I have studied the relevant documentation but it didn't strike my mind. Any kind of suggestion would be highly appreciated. Also, tell me if I am thinking in a wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

Let me clarify, you want to initialize the BRAM with some data, then make some processing on it, then auto-magically download it to the PC and make further analysis? If I am right, you need also to clarify, if you need production solution or debug solution, for production you need to design a data-dump module and connect it to specific communication module, but for debug purposes you can do it using jtag (be aware, dumping bram content at runtime using jtag will corrupt your data! make sure that circuit is stopped and nothing is updating bram during dumping), if you have Zynq device you can try with:

https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/7-Series-FPGAs/read-bram-from-jtag-or-uart-or-zynq-PS/td-p/738600

otherwise try with `readback` feature of 7series fpga's

https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp1230-configuration-readback-capture.pdf

Comment: yes I need to download data to the PC and make further analysis. i need it for production solution not debugging so I can have my data after process. I'm working with Virtex 5 and the only module I have on my board is PCIe.  is it possible to do this? @mucka